# rails categorizing nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have users with nested resources posts. I have a page that shows all posts from all users. However, on the left column I want to categorize them by user, as follows, with links to a URL with a parameter like `?username=laura`, for example, to show only their posts. I'm pretty sure I can figure out the URL params, but getting them sorted, as shown below, is difficult for me. Any suggestions? Thanks!

[Adam (23)](http://google)

[Brad (12)](http://google)

[Mike (1)](http://google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Users.includes(:posts).map{|u| [u.name, u.posts.count, u.id]}.sort
```

Will give you a sorted array of users, post counts, and user id like

```
[
 ["Adam", 23, 23],
 ["Brad", 12, 2],
 ["Mike", 1, 44]
]
```

You can this user the first two elements for your link and the user id for the link destination.

This might get slow with thousands of users and/or posts, but it should get you started.

Comment: Well I only need these for a group of selected posts. I have run a query on posts and get them saved in @posts_query ... how could I do this, but only within my query?

Answer (score -1):

You should sort them:

```
@sorted_users = users.sort { |left,right| left.posts.count <=> right.posts.count }
```

Also, if you have a cache_column for posts, you should probably use the database to implement this.

Comment: No, it's in there in all rails versions, in this case it would be class Post < ActiveRecord::Base; belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true; end and the User class would have to have a **posts_count** column and it could be used for sorting without loading the posts.